Can the V22 Osprey glide after dual engine failure while cruising?
In the event of complete power failure, if the aircraft is at cruise phase having transitioned to horizontal flight, can it glide and land?
If so, how does it deals with the propellers not having enough ground clearance while in  horizontal mode?

As I recall, the rotors can be feathered, similar to the propellers on any other multi engine airplane. Upon impact with an object, the blades are designed to be frangible and shatter into strand like sections.  Think of cooked spaghetti attached to the hub.

oh ok, so there would be indeed a prop strike

Only partially answered in Can the V-22 autorotate?: "if required, the V-22 can glide for a predictable run-on landing in airplane mode, much like a turboprop" .

Even a rock has a measurable glide ratio of <some_laughable_fraction>:1. The situation is similar with the Osprey. It's not designed to "glide" at anything remotely like a usable ratio, so instead it is designed to be survivable on impacts that would shred most other aircraft.
